# XSLT select issue -

Tags: xslt

I have some XSLT which is used to select text which has a particular keyword `<sliceXML>` This works fine and grabs each paragraph in turn. I also want to select the contents of the page tag `<pg>` and display it.

However it keeps selecting the value of the first `<pg>` tag and does not move onto the next. Any help is much appreciated.

**My XML**

```
<para>
    <sliceXML>telescope</sliceXML>
    A telescope test can be used to observe the night sky. What
    observations can you make about the universe from your own back yard?
    <pg>Page: 77</pg>
 </para>

 <para>
    <sliceXML>telescope</sliceXML>
    The scientists using the Sloan Digital Sky Survey telescope can
    gather far more information than they can review quickly. Humans are
    better at galaxy identification than computers. Why might this be a
    difficult task for computers?
    <pg>Page 78</pg>
 </para>
```

NOTE: Page 77 and Page 78

**My XSLT**

```
<xsl:template name="para">
    <div id="para">
        <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
    <span class="pagetag">
        <xsl:value-of select="//pg"/><img src="images/arrows.png" height="12px"/>
    </span>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

**My Current Results**

A telescope test can be used to observe the night sky. What observations can you make about the universe from your own back yard? **Page: 77**

The scientists using the Sloan Digital Sky Survey telescope can gather far more information than they can review quickly. Humans are better at galaxy identification than computers. Why might this be a difficult task for computers? **Page: 77**

**My Desired Results**

A telescope test can be used to observe the night sky. What observations can you make about the universe from your own back yard? **Page: 77**

The scientists using the Sloan Digital Sky Survey telescope can gather far more information than they can review quickly. Humans are better at galaxy identification than computers. Why might this be a difficult task for computers? **Page: 78**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try `pg` instead of `//pg`? Because you want the `pg` that is a child of your `para`.

Comment: You sir just saved my Friday night. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile, but maybe .//pg instead of //pg

Comment: In case it's not a direct child of para — yes, if it is, `pg` should suffice

Answer (score 0):

Following works fine for me

**XML:**

```
<form>
<para>
    <sliceXML>telescope</sliceXML>
    A telescope test can be used to observe the night sky. What
    observations can you make about the universe from your own back yard?
    <pg>Page: 77</pg>
 </para>

 <para>
    <sliceXML>telescope</sliceXML>
    The scientists using the Sloan Digital Sky Survey telescope can
    gather far more information than they can review quickly. Humans are
    better at galaxy identification than computers. Why might this be a
    difficult task for computers?
    <pg>Page 78</pg>
 </para>
 </form>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">

    <xsl:template match="form/para">
    <div id="para">
        <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
    <span class="pagetag">
        <xsl:value-of select="pg"/><img src="images/arrows.png" height="12px"/>
    </span>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" id="para">

    A telescope test can be used to observe the night sky. What
    observations can you make about the universe from your own back yard?

 <span class="pagetag">Page: 77<img src="images/arrows.png" height="12px"/></span></div>

 <div xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="para">

    The scientists using the Sloan Digital Sky Survey telescope can
    gather far more information than they can review quickly. Humans are
    better at galaxy identification than computers. Why might this be a
    difficult task for computers?

 <span class="pagetag">Page 78<img src="images/arrows.png" height="12px"/></span></div>
```